# Should I use animation or simple object rotation in this case

Tags: animation, rotation, unreal-4

I'm making game where players control hover tanks using Unreal Engine 4.
Tank have a turret which rotates around for aiming. Turret pivot/center of mass is not exactly in joint with rest of tank so it rotates around point behind the turret.
You can see it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k_d4u6Htzg

I asked my friend who made this mesh to create skeleton for it.
Now I'm not sure, which is the best way to implement correct rotation.

Should I make and use animation of tower rotating?
Keeping turret as child of rest of tank and simply rotating it was easier and more straightforward, so maybe I should just change pivot position?
Maybe, there is some easy way to rotate turrent around bone?

Which way is best in Your opinion and why?

Comment: The best way to proceed is up to you. If you think you'll need a more complex animation skeleton for later features, might as well make one now. If all you want is for the turret to rotate, don't bother changing your current setup if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I'm making this project to learn something and I was afraid that I'll do something stupid, just beacause that works.